# Getting error during create list in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

I am trying to fetch the data from database using database first approach and want to display the data in a list.. I am trying the following code for this

This is my Action method

```
 public ActionResult transaction()
        {

            var result = from T in db.tbProcTransactions
                         select T.pServiceID;
            return View(result);
        }
```

and in my view I write this

```
@model IEnumerable<LinQuery.Models.tbProcTransaction>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "transaction";
}

<h2>transaction</h2>

@foreach (var serviceID in @Model.pServiceID)
{
    @serviceID;
}
```

But when I run this code I get this Error

> *System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'pServiceID' and no extension method
>   'pServiceID' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)*

I am unable to resolve this error Please resolve this error experts

Comment: is this possibly http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx ?

Comment: You are returning an `IEnumerable<typeof(pServiceID)>`. Simplest solution is to use `select T;` instead of `select T.pServiceID;`

Answer (score 2):

Change your `foreach` statement to

```
@foreach (var serviceID in Model)
{
  @serviceID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Action select T instead of T. pServiceID

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@model IEnumerable<LinQuery.Models.tbProcTransaction>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "transaction";
}

<h2>transaction</h2>

@foreach (var serviceID in Model)
{
    serviceID.pServiceID;
}
```